# Docker container doesn't start due to CMD and ENTRYPOINT

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu
.........................
.........................
.........................
# install magento script
ADD script.sh /
RUN chmod +x /script.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["bash", "-c"]
CMD ["/script.sh"]
```

**Docker Build**

```
docker build -t test/magento2:1.0.0 .
```

**Docker Run**

```
docker run -it -d --name docfiletest -h www.hostname.net -e BASE_URL=http://www.hostname.net/ -v /u01/docker/volumes/2.1.6:/var/www/html -p 7012:80 --net mynetwork --ip 172.18.0.14 --privileged test/magento2:1.0.0
```

**Docker logs**

```
[bu@bu docker]$ docker logs docfiletest
[SUCCESS]: Magento installation complete.
[SUCCESS]: Magento Admin URI: /admin
```

**script.sh** run successfully

**Docker ps**

```
[bu@bu docker]$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS                    NAMES
5e3e593960f5        test/magento2:1.0.0                 "bash -c /script.sh"     26 minutes ago      Exited (0) 7 minutes ago                             docfiletest
```

It never get started.

I doubt here `command -> "bash -c /script.sh"` . I thought I'm missing something in CMD and ENTRYPOINT.

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: It started 26 minutes ago and exited 7 minutes ago. Can you check `docker events`?

Comment: yes it is showing correct. it means container created 26 minutes ago,  exited 7 minutes mention my last try `docker start docfiletest` it started and exit in few seconds.

Comment: Does the script run anything? It looks like it finished and is done, container exists but no process is running

Comment: Yes you right script finished execution like start  service and  install magento. but I can't understand, how to keep awake my container until I stop my container.

Comment: your container should do something , launch Magento or something else, the Nginx image maunches Nginx, the Mysql image launches Mysql...

Comment: do you mean make `script.sh` never ending? @user2915097 like run nginx in foreground...

Comment: yes, a container lives as long as it has something to do, you may add `;sleep infinity` at the end of your script

Comment: thanks buddy. it works! is it good practice? if not, what is the proper way?

Comment: What is the point of your image? DO you want to reuse it with in another Dockerfile, something like  `FROM test/magento2:1.0.0`?

Comment: nope! I don't inherit this image to another dockerfile

Comment: I think giving a `tail -f /dev/null` at the end than `sleep infinity` is better though.